# HTML5 video elements audio attribute question

Tags: html

Can some one explain the video elements audio attribute to me in laymans terms?

What exactly does it do?

And what values can it have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specification of the Video tag here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp

**Audio**
**Valid Values:** muted
Specifies the default state of the the audio. Currently, only "muted" is allowed

Comment: is muted the only value allowed? I thought I read a list somewhere a long time ago?

Comment: Only either blank or muted is allowed.

Comment: I notice that you are new to StackOverflow. When you are happy and feel that your question is answered, please click the Tick next to the answer you feel answered your question the most. :) I hope your project goes well.